# Reverse for 'edit_user' with arguments '(2L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Tags: django

I have an app named mylibrary where a user can add books. So I'm registering and logged in user and redirect them to index page. Here is what it looks like:

[mylibrary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xGLE.png)

You can see the drop down menu there's an option, My Profile. This is being generated from base.html. Here's the piece of code I was using:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuDivider">
      <li><a>Signed in as <br/>{{ user.username }}</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'mylibrary:edit_user' user.id %}">My profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'mylibrary:index' %}">My Library</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="{% url 'mylibrary:logout_user' %}">Sign out</a></li>
</ul>
```

This part generates the dropdown menus. So in this part :

```
<li><a href="{% url 'mylibrary:edit_user' user.id %}">My profile</a></li>
```

I'm taking the user id to sort out which user is currently logged in and trying to update his profile.
This is in the view class to edit the  profile:

```
@login_required
def edit_user(request, pk):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    user_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user)

    ProfileInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(User, UserProfile,
                            fields=('address', 'sex', 'phone', 'city', 'bio'))
    formset = ProfileInlineFormset(instance=user)

    if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.id == user.id:
        if request.method == "POST":
            user_form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
            formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)

            if user_form.is_valid():
                created_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
                formset = ProfileInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=created_user)

                if formset.is_valid():
                    created_user.save()
                    formset.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/mylibrary/edit_user/')

        return render(request, "mylibrary/account_update.html", {
            "noodle": pk,
            "noodle_form": user_form,
            "formset": formset,
        })
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

Here's my URL for the edit_user:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\-\w]+)/accounts/update/$', views.edit_user, name='account_update'),
```

So as soon as the app start, it is supposed to redirect to the index page or mylibrary home page. But when I'm adding

```
<li><a href="{% url 'mylibrary:edit_user' user.id %}">My profile</a></li>
```

this part to so that, now users can edit their profile, it generates above error.
How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `name='account_update'` in your URL pattern, but are trying to reverse it using `'mylibrary:edit_user'`.

You need to change one of them to match the other, for example:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[\-\w]+)/accounts/update/$', views.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
```

Comment: I changed the code like you said but this time it's giving

In template /home/shamsad/PycharmProjects/Onlinebookshare/templates/mylibrary/index.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '(2L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'mylibrary/$']

where my index.html loks like:
 {% extends 'mylibrary/base.html' %}

the rest of the index.html code has nothig to do with the profile part.

Comment: That suggests that you have a URL tag `{% url 'mylibrary:index' user.id %}`. It shouldn't have the `user.id` if the index URL pattern doesn't take the user_id. If you have changed the view or template, then restart your server to make sure you're not running old code.